# Printing reports and tables from an Activity in android

Tags: android-print-framework

I have say a listview, populated with the datas, in an activity.Now I want my app to print this listview to a printer, through google cloud print.How can this be done easily.I am using kitkat.I have wasted much time on google but could'nt find solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take the data and [create a pdf fairly easily](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html).  Pdfs can be sent to any pdf reader application using an intent and printed from there.  Alternatively you could integrate with the [Print framework and print from inside your app](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#draw-content).  If this is an approach that you are interested in I can provide more details as necessary.